# How to activate a script after the button is press? [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-loading

I need to activate cpa lead when the button is press.

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cpalead.com/mygateway.php?pub=52514&amp;gateid=NjE1Njk%3D"></script>.
```

And the button is just `<input type="button" />`

So I need to activate the `<script>` after the button is clicked. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have this button as:

```
<input type="button" id="activator" />
```

and then your JS Code

```
  var loaded = false;
  $("#activator").click(function(){
     if (!loaded) {
        $.getScript("http://www.cpalead.com/mygateway.php?pub=52514&amp;gateid=NjE1Njk%3D",  function(){ loaded = true; });
     } else {
        alert("script already loaded");
     }
     return false;
  });
```

Not tested, but as documented in the JQuery documentation, it should work...

## References:

- [JQuery getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: And remember, if it works for you you can accept that answers as the `answer`

Comment: Nope it still goes to a new page.